# How to make a program for password authentication

Tags: javascript, function, passwords

I've been working on this program and it just stops working and I can't figure the program out. I need the program to make sure that the password is over 8 characters, that it starts with a letter, and that it uses at least one number. I have to use most of the code as below, such as document.write and prompt, just because that is what we have used in class.

Here's the code:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            //Counting how many X's will cover the charachters
            function xCount(){
              var x = 0
                for(x=0; i<=password.length; x++){
                    document.write ("X")
                 return x
                }

            }
        </script>    
        </head>


        <script type="text/javascript">

            //Declaring variables
        var password = prompt ("Please Enter Your New Password." , "Enter Here")
        var passwordLength = parseInt(password.length)
        var passLength = 0
        var passwordLetter = 0
        var passwordNumber = 0


            //Making sure password is more then 8 charachters
        if(password.length >= 8){
                passLength = 1
        }

        if(password.length < 8){
                alert ("Invalid - Password is too Short")
                passLength = 0
        }

            //Checking for the First Letter being a Letter
        if(password.substr(0,1)>= "A" && password.substr(0,1)<="Z"){
                passwordLetter = 1
        }

        else{
                alert ("Invalid- Password does not start with a letter")
                passwordLetter = 0
        }

            //Checking if the password has a number in it
        for(i=0; i<=password.length; i++){
            password = parseInt (password)
            if (password.substr(i,1)>= 0 && password.substr(i,1)<=9){
                passwordNumber = 1
                }

                else{
                alert ("Ivalid- Password does not have a number.")
                passwordNumber = 0
                    }
        }


        if(passLength == 1 && passwordLetter == 1 && passwordNumber == 1){
            xCount()
            document.write ("Your password is " + xCount() + " has been accepted.")}



        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: check the browser developer tools for errors - are there any?

Comment: does your class not let you use regular expressions?

Comment: Also, console.log not document.write. Bad things can happen with doc writing in regards to dom (i see someone told you to do this. tell them i said it's bad lol)

Comment: you have a syntax error in what you posted when i pop it into a fiddle. it shows in the dev console. check your code. hint:https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substring.asp

Answer (score 0):

Are you familiar with Regular Expressions?
If you are not W3 has some great resources.

If I were you I would do something like this.

```
function CheckPassword(inputtxt) 
{ 
var passw=  /^[A-Za-z]\w{7,14}\d$/;  // this is a regex
if(inputtxt.value.match(passw))      // here you check the input against that regex
{ 
return true;
}
else
{ 
return false;
}
}
```

Let me know if you need further help understanding this and I can help out.
You can use this link to play with and understand Regex better 
https://regex101.com/

Comment: There are tons of regex variations that you could use to accomplish this. I was just sharing something simple to have a point come across. You could use something like ^[A-Za-z](?=.*[a-z])(?=.*).{7,16}$ .. The point here is that the best way to accomplish this task is by using regexs.

Comment: There is no confusion in answering a question a certain way when exacts and specifics are not given. Instructions do not say the number has to be in the middle just as much as it does not say it has to be at the end. I gave an answer to help not to confuse. \d is much more clear than ^[A-Za-z](?=.*[a-z])(?=.*).{7,16}$. He can then figure out exactly how/where he wants things.

Comment: And what requirement did I not meet? My answer would meet all of them.

Comment: I am talking about my first answer that you downgraded. The second one, I went for over 8 char long I know it does not meet requirements.

Comment: I guess we are not understanding each other. My first pattern has at least 8 digits, it needs to start with a letter and it needs at least one number. He did not say it has to be in the middle or at the end. Therefore I took the liberty to do the simplest expression (for his understanding). Now if the instructions said that the number had to be anywhere then you would be right. The instructions do not say that so I can enforce a rule.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the dev console for your errors. You see that "*substr*" is not a function. The correct function is *substring*. After fixing those, you'll notice that lower case letters will be seen as incorrect. Looking at ascii codes, there are non letters between upper and lower case letters. So you'd need two checks, one for A-Z and one for a-z.
Also, you redefined the "password" variable, which confuses it. We need to make a different thing to call that second one. And it's a number, so you can't use substring there. Check it for NaN.
Lastly, because it's in a loop, it alerts a lot. Let's fix that with a break on invalid input.

Try this.

```
<html>
<body>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        //Counting how many X's will cover the charachters
        function xCount(){
          var x = 0
            for(x=0; i<=password.length; x++){
                document.write ("X")
             return x
            }

        }
    </script>    
    </head>


    <script type="text/javascript">

        //Declaring variables
    var password = prompt ("Please Enter Your New Password." , "Enter Here")
    var passwordLength = parseInt(password.length)
    var passLength = 0
    var passwordLetter = 0
    var passwordNumber = 0


        //Making sure password is more then 8 charachters
    if(password.length >= 8){
            passLength = 1
    }

    if(password.length < 8){
            alert ("Invalid - Password is too Short")
            passLength = 0
    }

    //Checking for the First Letter being a Letter
    var firstchar=password.substring(0,1);
    if((firstchar >= 'A' && firstchar <= "Z") || (firstchar >= 'a' && firstchar <= "z")){
            passwordLetter = 1
    }

    else{
         alert ("Invalid- Password does not start with a letter")
          passwordLetter = 0
    }

        //Checking if the password has a number in it
    for(i=0; i<=password.length; i++){
        passwordNumber = parseInt (password)
        console.log(passwordNumber);
        if (! isNaN(passwordNumber)){
            passwordNumber = 1
            }

        else{
            alert ("Invalid- Password does not have a number.");
            passwordNumber = 0;
            break;
            }
    }


    if(passLength == 1 && passwordLetter == 1 && passwordNumber == 1){
        xCount()
        document.write ("Your password is " + xCount() + " has been accepted.")}



    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: I can't promise this is 100% correct but it should get you going.

Comment: Thank you for the help! just need to work on looking for the number and the final display.